# How to do stroke-opacity:0 with d3

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js, svg

Here is my code. My target - do intervals between slices in pie chart.

```
chart.svg.selectAll('path')
       .style('stroke-opacity','0.0')
       .style('stroke-width','10');
```

I think if stroke opacity will be 0 on piechart slices on web page it will be similar to interval between slices.
Problem: if stroke opacity equals to zero that doesn't work. If equals to number from 0.1 to 1.0 - all works. But I have another color from background.
Please give a hand to beginner! Thanks for attention and have a nice day.

Comment: this is not detailed enough for me to assist

Comment: what does 'doesn't work' mean?

Comment: I think if stroke opacity will be 0 on piechart slices on web page it will be similar to interval between slices.

Comment: Are you looking for something like [*Pie Padding*](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/f098d146315be4d1db52)?

Comment: Yes.That is exactly what I'm looking for! Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe the problem comes from the misconception that, when you set `stroke-opacity` to 0, the stroke will be transparent and reveal the background colour, and the fill of the element will end at the internal limits of the stroke. But, in fact, if you set the `stroke-opacity` to 0, you'll reveal the fill of the element (and the background colour, once the stroke goes inwards and outwards in the default stroke-alignment).

Look, for instance, at this example:

```js
var svg = d3.select("body")
.append("svg")
.attr("width", 300)
.attr("height", 300);

var color = d3.scale.category10();

data = [10, 20];

var rects = svg.selectAll(".rect")
.data(data)
.enter()
.append("rect");

rects.attr("x", function(d){ return d*10})
.attr("y", 0)
.attr("width", 100)
.attr("height", 80)
.attr("fill", function(d){ return color(d)})
.attr("stroke-width", 10)
.attr("stroke", "white")
.attr("stroke-opacity", 0);

var rects2 = svg.selectAll(".rect2")
.data(data)
.enter()
.append("rect");

rects2.attr("x", function(d){ return d*10})
.attr("y", 100)
.attr("width", 100)
.attr("height", 80)
.attr("fill", function(d){ return color(d)})
.attr("stroke-width", 10)
.attr("stroke", "white");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.17/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Both the pairs of rectangles are absolutely equal:

```
rects.attr("x", function(d){ return d*10})
 .attr("y", 0)
 .attr("width", 100)
 .attr("height", 80)
 .attr("fill", function(d){ return color(d)})
 .attr("stroke-width", 10)
 .attr("stroke", "white")
```

The only difference is that, in the upper pair, I add:

```
.attr("stroke-opacity", 0);
```

And that is the same of having no stroke.

You can see that, independent of the stroke alignment, the area and the size of the element is the same. Check the default stroke:

[image]

The rect element, outlined by a black line, remains the same.

To finish, I just found this fiddle (I don't know who's the author), and I set the stroke to white and stroke-width to 10: this is what you want, imitating a real padding. But you'll not get this result setting the stroke opacity to 0: https://jsfiddle.net/j1769sx2/

Comment: Thanks a lot for help! But color of my background is different. So I have another question: how to do stroke transparent for background color?

Comment: You can make the stroke with the same color of the background, but not transparent. Or, you can search for "padding" in pie charts.

Comment: Thanks again. In my project better is set color as background. Have a nice day!

Comment: No worries. But have a look at padding, its very simple, just `var pie = d3.layout.pie().padAngle(someValue);` changing someValue for whatever you want.